# Having trouble with web scraping coinmarketcap in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest

I am trying to scrape cryptocurrencies historical prices from the website named "coinmarketcap" but I could not make it. I know there is a lot of thread about this topic, I tried almost all of them but all the ways did not work for me. I am using Windows 10, I tried inspect method. Where am I doing wrong? My code is:

```
dataurl = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/"

data = dataurl %>% read_html()

data = data %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table')

data = data %>% html_table() %>% data.frame()
```

After this, "data" variable looks "0 obs. of 0 variables"

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this will work with `rvest` because the content is dynamic rather than static.  The `table` element isn't loaded when the source is read into R.  I was able to do this with `RSelenium` based on [this tutorial](https://thatdatatho.com/tutorial-web-scraping-rselenium/), though note you've got to at least install phantomJS first.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)

driver <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", phantomver="2.0.0")
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$open()

remote_driver$navigate("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/")

tab <- remote_driver$findElement(using="class", value="cmc-table")
tab_txt <- tab$getElementText()[[1]] 
mytab <-  read_delim(tab_txt, delim=" ", col_names=FALSE, skip=1)
mytab$X1 <- with(mytab, paste(X1, X2, X3, sep=" "))
mytab <- mytab %>% select(-c(X2,X3))
names(mytab) <- c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Market Cap")
head(mytab)
# # A tibble: 6 x 7
#    Date         Open       High       Low       Close     Volume         `Market Cap`   
#   <chr>        <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>          <chr>          
# 1 Aug 23, 2021 $49,291.68 $50,482.08 $49,074.… $49,546.… $34,305,053,7… $931,244,272,4…
# 2 Aug 22, 2021 $48,869.10 $49,471.61 $48,199.… $49,321.… $25,370,975,3… $926,961,622,3…
# 3 Aug 21, 2021 $49,327.07 $49,717.02 $48,312.… $48,905.… $40,585,205,3… $919,092,181,7…
# 4 Aug 20, 2021 $46,723.12 $49,342.15 $46,650.… $49,339.… $34,706,867,4… $927,189,789,0…
# 5 Aug 19, 2021 $44,741.88 $46,970.76 $43,998.… $46,717.… $37,204,312,2… $877,875,534,8…
# 6 Aug 18, 2021 $44,686.75 $45,952.06 $44,364.… $44,801.… $32,194,123,0… $841,823,296,2…
```

You may want to be able to hit the "Load More" button programmatically.  I was able to get access to the button as such.

```
button_element <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'class', value = "x0o17e-0")
```

Though I don't know if this class name is fixed or varies by session.  Also, when I did:

```
replicate(25, button_element$clickElement())
```

which should click the button 25 times, it just popped up a dialog asking me to login.  You can manually hit the button on the website that is driven by RSelenium (you should have a browser that has a red-striped address bar that is being driven by R.  When I hit that button a few times, and then executed the code to read in the table, the new table had more rows (i.e., it had responded to the load more button being pressed).

Comment: Thank you Dave, I will look at this tomorrow.