# Web scraping with R and rvest when javascript-rendered content in the web page

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to scrape the webpage https://www.filmweb.no/kinotoppen/ for title and other information under each movie. For other webpages I have been fine with running a couple of lines with html_nodes() and html_text() using SelectorGadget to pick the CSS selectors to get the different things I wanted as such:

```
html <- read_html("https://www.filmweb.no/kinotoppen/")
title <- html %>% 
  html_nodes(".Kinotoppen_MovieTitle__2MFbT") %>% 
  html_text()
```

However, when running those lines on this webpage I only get an empty character vector. Upon inspecting the webpage further I see that it is calling on javascripts.
I tried using html_nodes("script") together with the v8 library to run the javascripts, but to no avail. I'm also unsure which scripts to run, so I tried all as such:

```
ct <- v8()
ct$eval(scripts[3])
```

Is there an easier way in general to get the webpage into a form where I can just use rvest?
I do not know anything about javascript.

Comment: You'll probably need RSelenium.  I posted another similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913204/having-trouble-with-web-scraping-coinmarketcap-in-r/68913735#68913735).

Comment: Do you want just the the top 10 info or other stuff?

Comment: All top 60 after pressing see the whole list ("Se hele listen"). Found a solution below with help from Dave, but more solutions are always welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what it would look like using RSelenium to get the page to load.

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- rsDriver(browser='chrome', port=4444L)
brow <- remDr[["client"]]
brow$open()
brow$navigate("https://www.filmweb.no/kinotoppen/")
h <- brow$getPageSource()
h <- read_html(h[[1]])
h %>% html_nodes(".Kinotoppen_MovieTitle__2MFbT") %>% 
  html_text()
# [1] "Spider-Man: No Way Home"              "Clifford: Den store røde hunden"      "Lise & Snøpels - Venner for alltid"  
# [4] "Familien Voff - alle trenger en venn" "Nightmare Alley"                      "Snødronningen"                       
# [7] "Scream"                               "Bergman Island"                       "Trøffeljegerne fra Piemonte"         
# [10] "Encanto"
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked and I will mark this as the accepted answer. Wish I could upvote you a hundred times! :) 
One question, does this require PhantomJS? Running rsDriver and looking at your other post I see it. I did not install it but RSelenium seems to have. I also saw it in one of the vignettes that I skimmed. I read that that project has been suspended, so will this work into the future?
Again, thank you so much :)

Comment: I have also been trying to press "Se hele listen" to get the whole list with:

button <- brow$findElement(using="css", value=".button_Button__3rp_c")
button$clickElement()

That I inserted after navigate and before  pagesource.
Any Idea why it does not work? When I manually click in the browser that pops up it does work.

Comment: I have found that for some reason, things that should work with `findElement()` don't always and in those cases I have better luck, for example, `brow()$executeScript()` with the appropriate javascript, for example: `brow$executeScript("document.querySelector('.search-form > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)').click()")` worked when the equivalent operation with the RSelenium functions didn't.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
I weirdly get an error when running your code:
Selenium message:javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click'). But I also tried inspecting the button and copying the JS path and then inserting .click() as you did above:
```brow$executeScript('document.querySelector("#root > main > div.contentwrapper_contentWrapper__TndLw > div.Kinotoppen_Kinotoppen__2crjn > div > div.Kinotoppen_MovieChartContainer__JFEcJ > div.Kinotoppen_ShowAllMovies__6tT_i > button").click()')``` and that worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Data is dynamically retrieved from a graphql query. You can replicate that query to get the JSON response containing all the desired data.

In this case I chose to look at using [httr2](https://httr2.r-lib.org/) and the [newish pipe operator](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/the-new-r-pipe/) (R 4.1.0)

For how to pipe the headers vector I looked at the solution given by [@MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69830243).

```
library(httr2)

headers = c(
  'Accept' = 'application/json',
  'Referer' = 'https://www.filmweb.no/',
  'Content-Type' = 'application/json',
  'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0'
)

params = list(
  'query' = 'query($date:String,$chartType:String,$max:Int){movieQuery{getMovieChart(date:$date,chartType:$chartType,max:$max){chartType periodStart periodEnd movieChartItem{pos posPrev admissions admissionsPrev admissionsToDate weeksOnList movie{title mainVersionId premiere poster{name versions{width height url}}}}}}}',
  'variables' = '{"date":"2022-02-04","chartType":"weekend","max":1000}'
)

data <- request("https://skynet.filmweb.no/MovieInfoQs/graphql/") |> 
  (\(x) req_headers(x,  !!!headers))() |>  
 req_url_query(!!!params) |> 
  req_perform() |> 
  resp_body_json()
```

Comment: Thank you for another solution. I quickly tried copying and running it now changing to the magrittr pipe and the old anynomous function syntax as I use 4.0.4 and it worked. I got a list with a lot of information and quickly inspecting it I can see some movie titles and numbers. Very nice. 
One question that might be silly but I know nothing of web development; can you check from inspect that data is retrieved from a graphql query? I assume that is not always the case as a quick google search says that grapql was publicly released in 2015.

Comment: You can tell because graphql is in the endpoint /URI. You could filter the XHR web-traffic on that string in the network tab of the browser. Also, the query string is a bit of a give-away. You should see all 60 results in the response and more info than displayed on the page. I would probably then apply a custom function to extract what you want from the parsed JSON object `data`.